# My webpage won't let me scroll?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a webpage where I have a div ("container") that is a parent to the div "rounded".  For some odd reason, the webpage doesn't let me scroll down even though both of the divs' height are larger than the screen.

Here's a jFiddle with the components that aren't working out: http://jsfiddle.net/pmg92/19/

Any ideas as to why this isn't working?

Comment: take `position:fixed` off `.container`

Comment: @Henesnarfel post that as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to take the `position:fixed` off the `.container` so that it allows the page to be scrollable

**EDIT**

Check this out here http://jsfiddle.net/pmg92/23/ I think this is what you are looking for.  I took out the non relevant css so don't just copy and paste to yours.  I eliminated your background rounded image in place of using `border-radius` because by using a background image you can't really shrink or expand depending on content.  This won't work on older browsers unless you use webkits and so on.

If you want to use an image I would suggest slicing the image between a top, bottom, and middle.  The top would contain the top section with the radii. The middle would be 1px tall that repeats vertical as needed.  The bottom would contain the bottom section with the radii.

Comment: I need the position of the container to be fixed, though.  Basically I have a header div (I didn't include it into the jsFiddle) that I don't want the 'rounded' div to intersect with.  So I need the container div to cut off just before the header, which has a fixed position.  That's why I need the container to be fixed.

Comment: @IsaiahBugarin post the html and css you have

Comment: @IsaiahBugarin if you are linking to other stylesheets/javascript/images please enter the entire url and not the absolute or relative links.  That way we can see all the images and everything else that should be there.  Either that or give us the exact url of what you are working on

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way to keep the navigation bar to "fixed".  If there's no way, then I'll just keep it like that.

Comment: If you notice in the new jsFiddle, the "rounded" and the header collide.

Comment: @IsaiahBugarin  I don't know exactly what you expect to accomplish.  there is no way for the top bar to be fixed and not eventually overlap the content on the page.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have the `position` of the `container` fixed.

Comment: I need the position of the container to be fixed, though.  Basically I have a header div (I didn't include it into the jsFiddle) that I don't want the 'rounded' div to intersect with.  So I need the container div to cut off just before the header, which has a fixed position.  That's why I need the container to be fixed.