# My webpage doesnt scroll down

Tags: html, css

I want to scroll over the page, but currently my website doesn't have a scroll bar and I already tried "overflow: scroll;" which is not included by original code but doesn't fixed anyway. I'm unable to get the rest of the page to scroll as it should. What is the other solution or how can I add scroll option on my webpage?

Any help is most welcome and much appreciated.

http://collabedit.com/xdyw2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My webpage won't let me scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406693/my-webpage-wont-let-me-scroll)

Comment: Another one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24246914/website-wont-scroll-down

Answer (score 0):

You need to change position fixed in your class of static to something else.